# How to add form after submit button?

Tags: php, wordpress, css, scss-lint

I have created one contest and when submit that contest then open form like full name and email id etc.in wordpress site.

I want to create quiz contest in wordpress site.
Like

1.Where is czechoslovakia?

1.Prague

2.America

3.Asia

I want to use here checkbox button.
How to do this?How to add this all in wordpress?

Comment: Which Plugins best and free for quiz contest?

Answer (score 0):

> you can add quiz with wordpress just use following link.

http://www.wpexplorer.com/create-quiz-wordpress/

http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-easily-create-a-quiz-in-wordpress/

Comment: hello, I have one query

Answer (score 0):

> you can use WP plugin for quiz

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pro-quiz/

> and if you want to add form after perform another action so you can use 
>   append function in javascript